# How to get the Financial Type name/label in Smarty template?

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, receipts, smarty

I am using Thank You letter template to generate donation receipt. After using Find Contributions, I then choose All Records and from Actions I choose Thank You Letters.

I can then add smarty logic and am able to show the contacts name and address as well as some things like date of contribution ($contribution.receive_date) and the total amount of contribution ($contribution.total_amount) and also the ID of the Financial Type ($contribution.financial_type_id)

But I am not able to figure out how to get the following:

- Financial Type Name ($contribution.financial_type_id.name does not work.. always returns 1)
- Contribution Source ($contribution.source does not work.. always returns blank)
- Financial Type Is Deductible ($contribution.financial_type_id.is_deductible does not work.. always returns 1)

I am basing what I am doing from this answer by Iowa Boy
[How to print USA tax receipt to individuals?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41120/how-to-print-usa-tax-receipt-to-individuals#41136)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well after MUCH testing and playing around, I figured out what I needed, and I post it here in hopes it will help other noobs...

- Financial Type Name was retreived using `$contribution.financial_type`
- Contribution Source was retrieved using `$contribution.contribution_source`
- Financial Type Is Deductible was not available in the data that was already retreived, so had to make another call to find that out. Using the Financial Type ID from `$contribution.financial_type_id`, I did the following:

  ```
  {crmAPI var='resultFinancialType' entity='FinancialType' action='get' id=$financial_type_id}
  {assign var="financial_type_is_deductible" value=$resultFinancialType.values[0].is_deductible}
  {if $financial_type_is_deductible eq '1'}
     {assign var="financial_type_is_deductible" value="Tax-Deductible"}
  {else}
     {assign var="financial_type_is_deductible" value="Non tax deductible"}
  {/if}
  ```